# Undefined in Handlebars helper function

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a custom helper as given below. Somehow value of the passed params (v1, v2, v2) gets undefined. Any pointers would be helpful.

Something.js:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('hasAccess', function(v1, v2, v3) {
    console.log(v1 + ', ' + v2 + ', ' + v3); //this gives undefined
    if (v1 && v2 && v3) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
});
```

and my template, as follows:

```
 {{#each list1}}
    <span>{{this}}{{#if hasAccess value1 value2 value3}}<sup>display-something</sup>{{/if}}</span>
 {{/each}}

getData() {
      const value1 = true;
      let value2 = true;
      let value3 = false;
      let list1 = [10, 20, 30];
   }
```

I am also new to UI so any suggestion to improve the code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your template.

First, `#if` requires a single argument, which it will evaluate for truthiness. In order to give `#if` the result of the `hasAccess` helper, we will need to parens to make the `hasAccess` evaluation a [subexpression](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#subexpressions).

Our template gets updated to:

```
{{#if (hasAccess value1 value2 value3)}}<sup>display-something</sup>{{/if}}
```

This prevents Handlebars from throwing an error, but the arguments to our `hasAccess` helper all have the value of `undefined`. This is because `value1`, `value2` and `value3` are not available to the [evaluation context](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#evaluation-context) within our `#each` loop. We will need to use paths in order to [access the parent context](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#changing-the-context).

Now our template becomes:

```
{{#if (hasAccess ../value1 ../value2 ../value3)}}<sup>display-something</sup>{{/if}}
```

Note: As `value1`, `value2` and `value3` all belong to our [root data context](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#root), we could alternatively do:

```
{{#if (hasAccess @root.value1 @root.value2 @root.value3)}}<sup>display-something</sup>{{/if}}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/w6zLbmvo/) for your reference.

As for suggestions on code improvement. I am of the opinion that the `if (true) { return true; }` style is an anti-pattern and is much more cleanly written as:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('hasAccess', function(v1, v2, v3) {
  return Boolean(v1 && v2 && v3); 
});
```